# replace text with regex php, I got this error

Tags: php, regex

```
<html>
<body>
<form name='form' method='post' action="">
Dork: <input type="text" name="dork" id="dork" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$ptn = "/(?:[a-z]{4,5}://[a-z.0-9]*\/)?([a-z.\?_=]*)([0-9]*)/";  // Regex
$str = $_POST['dork']; //Your input, perhaps $_POST['textbox'] or whatever
$rpltxt = "$1";  // Replacement string
echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
?>
```

I got this error

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/'
```

How to fix it like this
http://prntscr.com/ex29j2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the slashes:

```
$ptn = "/(?:[a-z]{4,5}:\/\/[a-z.0-9]*\/)?([a-z.\?_=]*)([0-9]*)/";  // Regex
//              here __^ ^
```

or use another delimiter

```
$ptn = "~(?:[a-z]{4,5}://[a-z.0-9]*/)?([a-z.?_=]*)([0-9]*)~";  // Regex
```

Comment: how to replace with empty string

Comment: @NYARUU.com: just use `""` in the replacement part.

Comment: ok thanks, how to remove " http:// " http://prntscr.com/ex2dk8 please correction $ptn = "~(?:[a-z]{4,5}://[a-z.0-9]*/)?([a-z.?_=]*)([0-9]*)~";  // Regex

Answer (score 0):

You are using unescaped slashes in the middle of your pattern: `//`
The first slash defines the pattern end and the second gets therefore interpreted as a modifier.
Escape both like:

```
/(?:[a-z]{4,5}:\/\/[a-z.0-9]*\/)?([a-z.\?_=]*)([0-9]*)/
```